# CakePHP 3 + JWT + Xampp: Unable to read HTTP Authorization Bearer Token

Tags: apache, cakephp, authorization, jwt, cakephp-3.0

I'm designing this CakePHP 3 application using ADmad's [CakePHP JWT Auth plugin](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth) and [Bravo Kernel's tutorial](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/).

I've followed the example and am able to generate the tokens by calling the token() method.

However, when I post requests back using the token in form of Authorization Bearer xxx included in the headers, CakePHP is not able to read it.

If I log the $request var, I see...

```
[_environment:protected] => Array
    (
        [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZTUyYTIxZC02Nzk1LTRlZTgtYjFhYi1mYmY1N2M4OTQxNDAiLCJleHAiOjE1MTAzMDQxNTZ9.GeO-UACG491JsACeWqXYGasISBTRc7g74wVQjde-gYY
        [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MIBDIRS] => D:/xampp7/php/extras/mibs
        [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME] => \xampp\mysql\bin
        [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF] => D:/xampp7/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
        [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR] => \xampp\php
```

...
...

```
    [REQUEST_URI] => /api/requesters/load-user-details.json
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /api/webroot/index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /api/webroot/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1509704194.57
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1509704194
    [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZTUyYTIxZC02Nzk1LTRlZTgtYjFhYi1mYmY1N2M4OTQxNDAiLCJleHAiOjE1MTAzMDQxNTZ9.GeO-UACG491JsACeWqXYGasISBTRc7g74wVQjde-gYY
    [ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] =>
```

As per Bravo Kernel's tutorial / ADmad's explanation, I've added the following lines in .htaccess to ensure Apache passes on the token..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

The token appears to be included in the headers .. but the plugin still keeps outputting ..

```
{
    "message": "You are not authorized to access that location.",
    "url": "/requesters/load-user-details.json",
    "code": 401,
}
```

Any clues on what to do next?

Thank you.

Comment: The next thing to do should be more debugging, dig into `Auth/JwtAuthenticate.php` to figure where exactly it bails out.

Comment: any hints? did you get it to work??